# WordPress RESTAPI - Restrict unknown

Tags: wordpress, api

I am not sure about the technical term for what I am looking. However, I have done this in Laravel using [middleware](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192041/laravel-token-middleware). I am trying to achieve same in WordPress RESTApi.

I am planning to make a site as a service using WordaPress rest api. That I will use for cross platform. Since anyone can access WordPress api it is too dangerous.

I want to block it for public and only who pass the access token (not JWT or oAuth) I wan to allow only them to access API. This how I can limit the access.

So if I make android app and pass the access token, it will have access but anyone who want to make app from my api they want be able to.

I hope I have explained it properly to understand. You can see my middleware code that might help to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

use wordpress jwt plugin that adds authentication for wordpress api https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks, I believe you are aware what exactly I am looking. Well, I would prefer to write own rather using plugin. Just for confirmation. Did you see my laravel code?